# Insert Select where not exists

Tags: mysql

Hello I'm still struggling with the following code

```
INSERT INTO m4zbv_mt_cfvalues (cf_id, link_id,value) 
    SELECT 87,link_id,1
    FROM m4zbv_mt_links WHERE Upper(`link_name`) like'%#VMWARE APPLIANCE DEFAULT PASSWORDS%'
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(select cf_id, link_id from m4zbv_mt_cfvalues where cf_id=87 and link_id=m4zbv_mt_links.link_id)
```

This section works fine:

```
INSERT INTO m4zbv_mt_cfvalues (cf_id, link_id,value) 
    SELECT 87,link_id,1
    FROM m4zbv_mt_links WHERE Upper(`link_name`) like'%#VMWARE APPLIANCE DEFAULT PASSWORDS%'
```

I'm unsure how I can pass the values for `m4zbv_mt_links.link_id` from the first select and how to integrate the `WHERE NOT EXISTS`

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `and` instead of `where` :

```
INSERT INTO m4zbv_mt_cfvalues (cf_id, link_id,value) 
SELECT 87,link_id,1
FROM m4zbv_mt_links WHERE Upper(`link_name`) like'%#VMWARE APPLIANCE DEFAULT PASSWORDS%'
and NOT EXISTS
               (select cf_id, link_id 
                from m4zbv_mt_cfvalues 
                where cf_id=87 and link_id=m4zbv_mt_links.link_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to do is avoid duplicates, just INSERT IGNORE (and remove the WHERE NOT EXISTS clause)